# Stack Overflow doesn’t allow me to post, says my post contains code, when my post does not contain any code at all

Tags: bug, code

The pic of post is as below. As you can see, there isn't any code in my post. But Stack Overflow keeps complaining about its formatting and never gets satisified and keeps complaining without letting me to post.

[image]

PS: [here](https://pastebin.com/KERgWgHK) is the post content, if you want to try.

Comment: Why are you putting the number list in a code block?

Comment: it wasnt in code block. But because stackoverflow was complaining, I tried to put it in code block. Still it is complaining.

Comment: I guess the downvotes are because this should have been asked on meta.stackoverflow.com not meta.stackexchange.com which is for network-wide issues. Yes, it's confusing and should be clearer, and yes, the downvoters should have commented instead of unhelpful drive-by downvotes. Can we have this migrated?

Comment: There have been similar question on meta.stackechange: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139600/stack-overflow-wont-let-me-post-code-i-dont-have-proper-formatting), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142979/your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-code). None of them helped me. So I created new one. I have no issue with moving this to meta.stackoverflow.

Comment: Probably has to do with your equations.

Comment: Finally able to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867601/can-quick-sort-partition-algorithm-result-in-different-arrangements-after-sing). Dont know what fixed it. Did some random edits.

Comment: In the future, I'd highly recommend using the trick [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294841/false-positive-i-get-this-error-but-cannot-find-any-reason-your-post-appears/294843?r=SearchResults&s=1|23.0116#294843) to isolate the cause of your issue before asking. (I'd vote to close this as a duplicate, but there are already enough votes to close as off-topic that my vote would be overridden.)

Comment: Also, to close voters: the code formatting filter is *not* only on Stack Overflow; it exists on other sites too. Questions about it are *not* off-topic as site-specific.

Comment: Never use code formatting if it is not code. Also, please proofread and edit your post as you have committed a number of English errors that detract from your message.

Comment: @S, I closed it [in accordance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342722/stack-overflow-doesn-t-allow-me-to-post-says-my-post-contains-code-when-my-pos#comment1147616_342722) with the reason given by Anir - the ***bug*** is the overriding of my correct reason with the "one specific site" reason. Your [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342722/stack-overflow-doesn-t-allow-me-to-post-says-my-post-contains-code-when-my-pos#comment1147620_342722) says you abstained for this reason. This is a case where one would flag, **I** have no error to correct.

Comment: Review instructions: "Leave Closed if this question is not appropriate for the site in its current state".

Comment: @Rob The post I linked to is an FAQ; the guidelines you cite in the review system itself are *simplified* versions of the real guidelines that don't necessarily take all possible cases into account. As well, duplicates aren't necessarily inappropriate for the site: they serve as signposts for searchability purposes. (This has meaning in the system's operationalization too: duplicates are exempt from the Roomba criterion that deletes closed questions after 9 days, and migrated questions aren't marked "rejected" if they are closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: Also, it's not a bug - it's the intended design of the system. I've written a whole post on how the system chooses close reasons based on votes.

Comment: Finally, the fact that the author was able to post by making random changes doesn't make the question no longer reproducible: the problem can still be reproduced by attempting to post the exact same text that they *originally* tried to post, and the question here asks specifically why that throws the error.

Comment: Just want to tell all, originally there were no code blocks on blockquotes and it was still giving same error. To deal with it, I tried to put code block.

Answer (score 4):

You have 5 spaces in front of the array you are attempting to display as code.

```
 60,80,15,95,7,12,35,90,55
```

After 4, it assumes that you were trying to write a code block, but that additional space confuses it possibly.

Removing one space "should" resolve the issue:

```
60,80,15,95,7,12,35,90,55
```

But you could also instead of using spaces backtick encapsulate it ( using ``` before the code line and after) to create a code block and then code doesn't need the 4 spaces in front any longer.

```
60,80,15,95,7,12,35,90,55
```

To note:

- Code blocks should be used for code.  One reason is that code blocks are not indexed in site searches (Not applicable here, but important to know).
- The formatting applies to all exchange sites.

This information is available to the right of the post as you are creating it and additionally the information displayed under the question body points to the additional space possibly being an issue.  Displaying exactly where would be nice (The first array in your question is the one with 5 spaces FYI), but it's the hint under the body section that led me to find the extra space.

Comment: How about code being used on code-review...

Comment: Originally I had no code blocks only blockquotes. Still it gave the same error.

Comment: @Luuklag Clarified what I meant, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @anir You have 5 spaces.  The system automatically makes a code block appear when you have 4 spaces as part of the formatting rules.  You may not have _meant_ to have a code block, but what you tried to post had one in it with an extra space according to the image you've shown above.